# Excel VBA for Unhiding or Hiding a Worksheet Conditionally Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have attempted many different times to formulate a code for this and even tried a few strings of code I found on this site, but I have been unable to find a resolution.

My goal is to have a hidden worksheet pop up as unhidden when the user selects "yes" from the dropdown in a cell on another worksheet for the user to enter their notes on then if the cell is populated at N/A or (Select) have the sheet remain hidden.

Could anyone help with this?

Here is the most recent code I attempted:

```
Sheets("Prop. Pres. Notes 206-261").Activate
If Range("G39").Value = "YES" Then
Sheets("Prop. Pres. Notes 206-261").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("Prop. Pres. Notes 206-261").Visible = False
End If
```

Comment: Sounds like you need this code placed in a `Worksheet_Change` macro. How have you been calling this code so far?

Comment: Is G39 on the same sheet as you are making visible/invisible?  If so, once the sheet is invisible, how are the users changing the value of G39?  (If it is by a formula in G39 which references the other cell containing the dropdown, it is that other worksheet which will need to have the `Worksheet_Change` and the code will need to check if the `Target` is the cell which the user is actually changing - not G39 on the sheet that is being hidden/unhidden.)

Comment: I am using it as a Worksheet_Change, and it is not on the same worksheet that I am hiding or un-hiding. It is on a separate sheet when they enter the yes value I want the sheet to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what sheet `Range("G39")` is on
If it's on Sheet1 try comparing lower case strings:

```vb
Sheets("Prop. Pres. Notes 206-261").Visible = LCase(Sheets(1).Range("G39").Value2) = "yes"
```

Comment: What would lower case do for me exactly? Just curious. The yes is on Sheet 1 in a drop down list, and it is capitalized.

Comment: In your description and comments you didn't mention it was capitalized, you used **"yes"**, so I was covering all possibilities; also, I'm not sure how the drop down list was created so I would go a step further and use `Trim(LCase(Sheets(1).Range("G39").Value2)) = "yes"` as well

Comment: I have a sheet with different lists on it for multiple different drop down lists, but the drop down for that is in there as well. I will try the trim, but there were no spaces around "YES". It is also spelled in all capitals.

Comment: Then it might be something else, but it would be helpful if we can compare the exact same values that VBA is comparing (maybe do Debug.Print for each value like `Debug.Print ">" & Sheets(1).Range("G39").Value2 & "<"` and the same for the drop down value)

Comment: I was able to use this type of code, but I found the glitch had to do with some of the cells that I was referencing not being set up exactly the way I thought. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Place this under your main sheet in Microsoft Excel Objects

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$G$39" Then
        'Change Sheet1 to the name of your main sheet
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G39").Value = "YES" Then
            Sheets("Prop. Pres. Notes 206-261").Visible = True
        Else
            Sheets("Prop. Pres. Notes 206-261").Visible = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is still not working correctly. It is hidden all the time and does not become un-hidden when the selection is "yes".

Comment: Are you using a dropdown list for the yes/no selection?

Comment: I am actually using a dropdown yes. The list is located on another sheet.

Comment: So when you select yes from the dropdown and hit the tab key, what happens?

Comment: Nothing. I see the same tabs the one that I have hidden stays hidden.

Comment: And you're certain that you have this code placed under the sheet specific tab under Microsoft Excel Objects?